# AWS Dedicated Host Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, amazon-billing

I am getting a bit confused with Dedicated Host Pricing. It will be great if someone can help me to understand my queries.

I have to launch Dedicated Host for one of my Project. What I understand is there be a Dedicated Machine that will be assigned to my account and I can launch instances on that Machine like typical On Demand EC2 Instance.

**Queries:**

1. Once I pay for the Dedicated On Demand Host, will I be also charged for the EC2 Instances that will be launched over top of it or it is like I have paid for Dedicated Host and now If I export my VM and launch on the Dedicated Host like normal EC2 there will be no additional charges and I will pay for only Dedicated Host Only.

Comment: Pricing page says: "Regardless of the quantity or the size of instances that you choose to launch on a particular Dedicated Host you only pay for each active Dedicated Host."

Comment: This answers my query. Thank you. I missed it in the documentation.

Comment: Please accept the supplied answer, if correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be charged any additional amount for EC2 instances that you launch on your EC2 Dedicated Host. You only pay for the host itself, and the price for a Dedicated Host varies by instance family, region, and payment option (On Demand, Reservation, or Savings Plan).

Per the [Amazon EC2 Dedicated Hosts Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/pricing/) page:

> Regardless of the quantity or the size of instances that you choose to launch on a particular Dedicated Host you only pay for each active Dedicated Host.